# recursion in JavaScript graph exploring algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I am trying to explore a graph here but I am not sure what is wrong with the explore function. The recursion doesn't seem to be working correctly; while exploring the neighbours of the node 0 it explored 0, 1, 2 and then never returns back to explore 3, 4, 5; why is that so?

```
explored=[]
//class definition 
function graph(){
    this.graph=new Array();
    this .graph[0] = [1,0,1,1,0,1]
    this .graph[1] = [0,1,1,1,0,0]
    this .graph[2] = [1,1,1,1,0,0]
    this .graph[3] = [1,1,1,1,1,0]
    this .graph[4] = [0,0,0,1,1,0]
    this .graph[5] = [1,0,0,0,0,0]

    this.explore    = explore

}

function explore(node,depth){

    explored[node]=1
    document.write('<br>')
    for(x=0;x<depth;x++)
        document.write('-')
    document.write(node+'<br>')
    neighbours=this.graph[node]

    document.write('exploring '+node +' neighbours' + neighbours +'explored = '+explored)

    for ( i=0;i<neighbours.length;i++){
        document.write('checking'+i+' node is ='+node )
        if(neighbours[i] ==1 && explored[i]!=1)
            this.explore(i,++depth)
    }

}

g = new graph()
g.explore(0,0)
```

Comment: by not using var you've set both x and i as global variables.

Comment: @generalhenry You should make it an answer, so he can accept it.. if not, I will do it.. mohowhah..mwhahahaha!

Comment: thanks a lot , and yeah u can make it an anwswer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by leaving out var you're setting global variables in a recursive function and stepping on your toes, here's the corrected code

```
function explore(node,depth){

    explored[node]=1
    document.write('<br>')
    for(**var** x=0;x<depth;x++)
        document.write('-')
    document.write(node+'<br>')
    **var** neighbours=this.graph[node]

    document.write('exploring '+node +' neighbours' + neighbours +'explored = '+explored)

    for (**var** i=0;i<neighbours.length;i++){
        document.write('checking'+i+' node is ='+node )
        if(neighbours[i] ==1 && explored[i]!=1)
            this.explore(i,++depth)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line `this.explore(i,++depth)` may also be causing you problems, as you
are incrementing depth in the current scope as well as passing the incremented 
value to the recusive call,

better to use

```
this.explore(i, depth + 1);
```

When in doubt with javascript it is always good to check the code with jslint.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't that be exactly equivalent? While he doesn't use the depth argument for the actual exploration, I think what he actually wants is `this.explore(i, depth + 1)` though - so that the depth isn't increased in the calling scope, and indentation will remain correct for that depth.